# Docusign iframe css

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign iframe is wider then my wrapper(html body). Is there a way to change the width of the content in the iframe? I can change the width of the iframe to match the page, but then I end up having a horizontal scroll bar.

Also, users need to sign a document that's like quarter of a page. But Docusign shows the whole page, and when I try to change the height, I get a horizontal scroll bar. There's also a lot of white space after the document. How can I get rid of the white space after the document? Is there a way to create a document in Docusign that's only half a page, or even less?

Here's what it looks like:
http://community.docusign.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/845iEC30DDC72CFD7F83/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to configure/change the amount of screen real estate the DocuSign signing session window consumes.  Whenever you're using the DocuSign API to facilitate embedded/captive signing within your site (as you are), best practice would be to launch the DocuSign URL in a new browser window/tab -- for a few reasons:

1. Some types of browsers have issues when external apps embedded in an iFrame try to write cookies (as DocuSign does).
2. Rendering DocuSign in an iFrame on a mobile device can result in a poor user experience, since DocuSign requires quite a bit of real estate and screen sizes on mobile devices are small  to start with.
3. Rending DocuSign in its own window allows you to avoid the scrolling issues you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to change the css of the iframe, why not just use [Docusign's API](http://iodocs.docusign.com/)?
Learn more about it [here](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center).

Comment: If I use the API, I still have to display an iframe or direct the user to docusign's website right? Or can I just display the signature box on my website? I want the user to sign the document on my website.

Comment: I would think that you could just display the signature box, but I've never used their API before.

Comment: If you want to embed the sending or signing experience (or even the DocuSign Console) into your website or app then yes you need to use an iFrame, however you can control the re-direct urls.  In fact, you can even re-direct to different urls based on the actions the user took.  For instance, you can re-direct to a custom url on signing complete, signing declined, window closed, etc.