# Docusign Embedded View Won't scroll to top in ie

Tags: docusignapi

So I have codebehind that creates the authetication token, passes in the document to be signed and returns the ViewUrl. This is done via WebMethod. I call this webmethod through jquery and the success callback returns the ViewUrl, which I then assign to an iframe. It works fine in every browser but there's one quirk in ie. Once the document isfinihsed loading, the screen jumps to the top of the document. This is not what the client wants. They want the very top of the page visible. It does this fine in every other browser except ie.

```
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'xxx.aspx/Get',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          data:{},
          success: function (data) {
          var docUrl = data.d;
          $('#fDocusign').prop('src', docUrl);
          $(document).scrollTop();
          var nav = $('.sidebar').offset();
          $('#fDocusignContainer').css({'position':'absolute','top':'475px','left':nav.left + 'px',width:$('.content').width() + 'px'});
          $('#fDocusign').css({ 'height': '1000px', width:$('.content').width() + 'px' });
          $('#fDocusignContainer').show();
          $('#spnMessage').text('');
          }
          });

          });
```

I tried using $(document).scrollTop() to force it tono avail. Any ideas?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454767

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @CodingDawg's comment

-- there's no need to use an iFrame. Just save your app's state with any of the techniques listed below and then do a redirect to the Signing Ceremony URL you received from DocuSign.

Saving state:

1. Your software stack may offer a session object, use that.
2. Save a handle to your state as a query parameter to the return_url you send to DocuSign. It will be returned to your app when DocuSign redirects back to your app after the signing ceremony is complete.
3. Save state in a cookie.